# Problema Simulador/Smartphone en Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

estoy desarrollando una app para mi proyecto final de grado y tengo un problema un tanto particular; en el simulador de Android Studio la app corre sin problemas, sin embargo, cuando pruebo la misma app en mi teléfono no corre bien, lo he probado en varios modelos y tienen el mismo problema.

La app tiene un contador que va descontando desde un tiempo dado (00:01:30) en formato hh:mm:ss, hasta llegar a cero (00:00:00), en el simulador llega hasta cero pero en el teléfono se queda parado en el último segundo (00:00:01).

¿Alguien sabe por qué? Adjunto la aplicación en .rar para que probéis.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8hswrw0xwjjlx3v/Helios.rar?dl=0

Comment: ¿La versión de android de los dispositivos que realizaste son iguales o mayores a la versión target o la versión mínima que colocaste?

Comment: Sí, los dos que he usado son Android 7.0 y API 24

Comment: ¿La maquina virtual es v.24 o es v.26?

Comment: En las caracteristicas pone API 27

Comment: veo que en el target de tu app pones v.26 y la minima la pones como v.21, los calculos matematicos deberian ser iguales en todas las versiones, pero por si acaso intenta poner  otro `updateTimer();` en `onFinish()` antes de  `timerRunning = false;` y dinos que sucede

Comment: Bueno, no es una solución "bonita" pero funciona, he conseguido apañarlo añadiendo como tú has dicho, un `updateTimer()` y `TextView_reloj.setText("00:00:00);` delante del `timerRunning = false;`

Comment: Agrega la solución acá abajo para que quede solucionada la pregunta, ademas de que ganaras una medalla ;)

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio David, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**